# Leer numericos de Excel en Java con Apache Poi

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi

Tengo una clase que se supone debe escribir y leer archivos de Excel. La creación se hace sin problema, pero cuando agrego mas filas al Excel creado y regreso al código a leerlos, no lee las celdas con valores numéricos.

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.util.Iterator;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Cell;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.CellStyle;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Font;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Row;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFCell;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFRow;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFSheet;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbook;

public class Leer {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    //EscribirEXCEL();

    LeerEXCEL();

}

private static void LeerEXCEL() {

    String nombreArchivo = "ListaUsuarios.xlsx";
    String hoja = "Usuarios";

    try(FileInputStream file = new FileInputStream(new File(nombreArchivo))){
        //Leer archivo de Excel
        XSSFWorkbook libro = new XSSFWorkbook(file);
        // Obtener la hoja que se va a leer
        XSSFSheet sheet = libro.getSheetAt(0);
        // Obtener todas las filas de la hoja de Excel
        Iterator<Row> rowIterator = sheet.iterator();

        Row row;
        // Se recorre cada fila hasta el final
        while(rowIterator.hasNext()) {
            row = rowIterator.next();
            // Se obtienen las celdas por fila
            Iterator<Cell> cellIterator = row.cellIterator();
            Cell cell;
            // Se recorre cada celda
            while(cellIterator.hasNext()) {
                // Se obtiene la celda en especifico y se imprime
                cell = cellIterator.next();
                System.out.print(cell.getStringCellValue()+ " - ");
            }
            System.out.println("");
        }

    } catch(Exception e) {
        e.getMessage();
    }
}

private static void EscribirEXCEL() {
    String nombreArchivo = "ListaUsuarios.xlsx";

    String hoja = "Usuarios";

    XSSFWorkbook libro = new XSSFWorkbook();
    XSSFSheet hoja1 = libro.createSheet(hoja);

    // Cabecera de la hoja de excel
    String[] header = new String[] {"NOMBRE", "TELEFONO", "EMAIL"};

    // Contenido de la hoja de excel
    String[][] document = new String[][] {
        {"Sergio P", "1234567", "sergiop@prueba.es"},
        {"Laura L", "4324251", "laural@prueba.es"},
        {"Juan H", "7363153", "juanh@prueba.es"}
    };

    // Poner en negrita la cabecera
    CellStyle style = libro.createCellStyle();
    Font font = libro.createFont();
    font.setBold(true);
    style.setFont(font);

    // Generar los datos para el documento
    for(int i = 0 ; i <= document.length ; i++) {
        XSSFRow row = hoja1.createRow(i); // Se crea la fila
        for(int j = 0 ; j < header.length ; j++) {
            if(i == 0) { // Para la cabecera
                XSSFCell cell = row.createCell(j); // Se crean las celdas pra la cabecera
                cell.setCellValue(header[j]); // Se añade el contenido
            } else {
                XSSFCell cell = row.createCell(j); // Se crean las celdas para el contenido
                cell.setCellValue(document[i - 1][j]); // Se añade el contenido
            }
        }
    }

    // Crear el archivo
    try (OutputStream fileOut = new FileOutputStream(nombreArchivo)){
        System.out.println("SE CREO EL EXCEL");
        libro.write(fileOut);
    } catch(IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
}
```

Este es el archivo de Excel que intento leer (la ultima fila, del usuario Luis es la que yo agregué manualmente):

```
NOMBRE  TELEFONO    EMAIL
Sergio P    1234567 sergiop@prueba.es
Laura L 4324251 laural@prueba.es
Juan H  7363153 juanh@prueba.es
Luis    12345   luis@prueba.es
```

Y la salida que tengo es esta:

```
NOMBRE - TELEFONO - EMAIL - 
Sergio P - 1234567 - sergiop@prueba.es - 
Laura L - 4324251 - laural@prueba.es - 
Juan H - 7363153 - juanh@prueba.es - 
Luis -
```

Hay algo mas que deba agregar al código para operar con numéricos insertados por el usuario sin problema? Saludos!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apache POI da bastante quebraderos de cabeza a la hora de leer las columnas porque cambia bastante dependiendo del tipo de dato de la celda. Por ejemplo para recuperar numéricos sería

```
cell.getNumericCellValue();
```

Es necesario revisar el tipo de celda que leemos porque no siempre va a ser texto. Con algo así podemos hacerlo.

```
if (cell.getCellType() ==  Cell.CELL_TYPE_STRING){
   // tratamos la celda en consecuencia
}
```

De todas formas, se podría forzar la conversión a String de esta manera aunque no es una forma correcta pues se puede perder precisión en la conversión del número.

```
cell.setCellType(Cell.CELL_TYPE_STRING);
```

Por lo que ciñéndonos a tu problema quizá con este aproximamiento lo tenemos

```
  // Se recorre cada fila hasta el final
            while(rowIterator.hasNext()) {
                row = rowIterator.next();
                // Se obtienen las celdas por fila
                Iterator<Cell> cellIterator = row.cellIterator();
                Cell cell;
                // Se recorre cada celda
                while(cellIterator.hasNext()) {
                    // Se obtiene la celda en especifico y se imprime
                    cell = cellIterator.next();
                    System.out.print(convertCellToString(cell)+ " - ");
                }
                System.out.println("");
            }
```

Ejemplo de función conversora

```
   public String convertCellToString(Cell cell){
       if (cell.getCellType() ==  Cell.CELL_TYPE_STRING){
       // tratamos la celda en consecuencia
            return cell.getStringCellValue();
        } else  if (cell.getCellType() ==  Cell.CELL_TYPE_NUMERIC) {
            return String.valueOf(cell.getNumericCellValue());
        }

    return "";
   }
```

Si por cualquier cosa esto no funcionara habría que revisar la versión que estás usando de Apache POI.